# How do I update state inside function in react native?

Tags: react-native

I have a simple  functional component, where depending on the state  I show "add item" or "remove item" button:

```
const SimpleComponent = ({ route }) => {
  const { id } = route.params;
  const [add, setAdd] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
      { isCurrentUserHavingThisItem(route, id) ?
        setAdd(true)
        :
        setAdd(false)
      }
  }, [])
  return (
    <View >
    { add ?
      (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => removeItem(route, id)}>
          <Text> Remove this item </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      )
      :(
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => addItem(route, id)}>
          <Text> Add item </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      )
    }
    </View>
  );
};

const isCurrentUserHavingThisItem = (route, id) => {
  firebase.firestore()
        .collection('Users')
        .doc(id)
        .collection('Items')
        .doc(route.params.item.key)
        .get()
        .then((docSnapshot) => {
          console.log("my return statement: ", docSnapshot.exists);
          setAttending(docSnapshot.exists);
          return docSnapshot.exists;
          })
        .catch((error) => {
          console.log(error);
          return false;
        });
}
```

I think that `isCurrentUserHavingThisItem` is working fine. However, when I press the "Add item" I trigger the following function:

```
const addItem = (route, id) => {
  firebase.firestore()
        .collection('Users')
        .doc(id)
        .collection('Items')
        .doc(route.params.item.key)
        .set({})
        .then(setAdd(true));
}
```

Which gives me the following error: `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: setAdd`  I also tried the following:

```
const addItem = (route, id) => {
      firebase.firestore()
            .collection('Users')
            .doc(id)
            .collection('Items')
            .doc(route.params.item.key)
            .set({});
      setAdd(true);
    }
```

but it gave me the same error. Here is the whole component structure for better visibility:

```
const SimpleComponent = ({ route }) => {
  const { id } = route.params;
  const [add, setAdd] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
      { isCurrentUserHavingThisItem(route, id) ?
        setAdd(false)
        :
        setAdd(true)
      }
  }, [])
  return (
    <View>
    { add ?
      (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => removeItem(route, id)}>
          <Text style={styles.title}>Remove item</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      )
      :(
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => addItem(route, id)}>
          <Text style={styles.title}>Add item</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      )
    }
 
    </View>
  );
};

const isCurrentUserHavingThisItem = (route, id) => {
  //same as I described it above; I think it works fine
}

const addItem = (route, id) => {
  //same as described above
  //gives me error when I try to update the state
}

const leaveMeetup = (route, id) => {
  //same as described above
  //gives me error when I try to update the state
}
export default SimpleComponent;
```

Basically, after I add the item successfully, I want to display "remove item" button and vice versa. In order to do so I try to update the state but as I said I have `ReferenceError: Can't find variable: setAdd` error and I dont see why. Can someone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your setAdd method is outside the component that's why it is showing that error...Please move your methods inside your functional component like this.

```
const SimpleComponent = ({ route }) => {
  const { id } = route.params;
  const [add, setAdd] = useState(false);

  const isCurrentUserHavingThisItem = (route, id) => {}

  const addItem = (route, id) => {}

  const leaveMeetup = (route, id) => {}

  useEffect(() => {
      { isCurrentUserHavingThisItem(route, id) ?
        setAdd(false)
        :
        setAdd(true)
      }
  }, [])
  return (
    <View>
    { add ?
      (
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => removeItem(route, id)}>
          <Text style={styles.title}>Remove item</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      )
      :(
        <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => addItem(route, id)}>
          <Text style={styles.title}>Add item</Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      )
    }
 
    </View>
  );
};


export default SimpleComponent;
```

and i think you can't do it like this.
`.then(setAdd(true));`

You get a callback in `.then()`

So the correct way to do this is

```
.then(()=>{
  setAdd(true)
 }).
```